# Combining price and add to cart button in one element

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I combine **price** and **"Add to cart"** button in one interactive element at

> Magento 2.1?

Now it looks like: [ $120 ] [ Add to Cart ]
How to make it look like: [ $120 Add to Cart ] ?

**Thank you so much**

.

Comment: which page ?????

Comment: Product page for example. And other places which contains "add to cart" button and price